# Where store the data in 2nd level cache in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Where store the data in 2nd level cache in Hibernate? Means the datas are store in database or in memory.

Comment: You're asking if you should store the data for a database cache... in a database?

Answer (score 0):

If the cached data would be stored in a database then it would not be a very good cache => in memory.

Comment: I assume it will be heap; why does this matter?